# Azure Bot Security against Bot Attacks

Tags: azure, security, botframework

I know there is a way to intercept messages that are sent to the bot but is there a different or better approach to deal with the following scenario:

I have a bot that uses several APIs. The more I use my APIs the more I will have to pay.
Some person with bad intensions also built a bot and that bot talks the whole time to my bot sending lots of lots of lots of spam and random messages. By doing so I will have to pay a waaay higher amount than expected.

Comment: Hi Anne! What is is you're looking to block? Just other bots interacting with your bot? Possible DDOS of your web app due to a conversation surge?

Comment: Indeed. A kind of DDOS if suspicious traffic is detected ! e.g. when one entity interacting with my bot sends so many messages that it just consumes my bill.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not a web security expert, but as a bot is just another form of web app, I imagine you would secure against DDOS or traffic surges against bots the same way as any other app. If you're looking to code that only a human can interact with your bot, thus limiting the amount of API calls over time to what a human can realistically create, you would want to look into making a form of login/registration before the client interacts with the bot, and institute some form of captcha.